# per_image_whitening in Python

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to set up TensorFlow to accept one image at a time but I believe I'm getting incorrect results because I pass a regular array without first performing tf.image.per_image_whitening() beforehand. Is there an easy way to do this in Python to an individual image without using the image queue?

Here's my code so far:

```
        im = Image.open(request.FILES.values()[0])
        im = im.convert('RGB')
        im = im.crop((0, 0, cifar10.IMAGE_SIZE, cifar10.IMAGE_SIZE))
        (width, height) = im.size
        image_array = list(im.getdata())
        image_array = np.array(image_array)
        image_array = image_array.reshape((1, height, width, 3))

        # tf.image.per_image_whitening() should be done here
        #mean = numpy.mean(image_array)
        #stddev = numpy.std(image_array)
        #adjusted_stddev = max(stddev, 1.0/len(image_array.flatten())))

        feed_dict = {"shuffle_batch:0": image_array}
        # predictions always returns something close to [1, 0]
        predictions = sess.run(tf.nn.softmax(logits), feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: Found a temporary solution, but it's really slow: image_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_array)
  with tf.Session():
   image_tensor_whitened = tf.image.per_image_whitening(image_tensor)
   image_array = image_tensor_whitened.eval()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the image queue and do the predictions one by one, I think

```
image_array = (image_array - mean) / adjusted_stddev
```

should be able to do the trick.

If you want to do the prediction by batches, it's a little bit complicated as  per_image_whitening (now per_image_standardization) only works with single images. So you need to do it before you form the batch like the way above or setup a preprocess procedure.